# Get a link text and element text based on a condition

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have to get the text and link of an element if there is 'theme-cell-card Ace' else not. Following is the sample html code:

```
<div class="theme-grid-cell-frame">
    <a href="/t/490">
        <div class="theme-cell">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="theme-cell-overlay deep"></div>
            <h1 class="theme-cell-name"> textqwqw</h1>
            <div class="theme-cell-card Ace"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="theme-grid-cell-frame">
    <a href="/o/434">
        <div class="theme-cell">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="theme-cell-overlay deep"></div>
            <h1 class="theme-cell-name"> textegg</h1>
            <div class="theme-cell-card Jack"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>    
<div class="theme-grid-cell-frame">
    <a href="/t/4665">
        <div class="theme-cell">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="theme-cell-overlay deep"></div>
            <h1 class="theme-cell-name"> textdgfh</h1>
            <div class="theme-cell-card Ace"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="theme-grid-cell-frame">
    <a href="/o/764">
        <div class="theme-cell">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="theme-cell-overlay deep"></div>
            <h1 class="theme-cell-name"> textgrth</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am able to get text of an element but I want to pass the condition `class="theme-cell-card Ace"` is true.

```
${grid}     Set Variable    //div[@class='theme-cell']
@{elements}    Get Webelements    ${grid}
:FOR   ${element}    IN    @{elements}
\    ${text}    Get Text    ${element}
```

I am a newbie, so please let me know if you need more info. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the robot framework but this is the XPath locator you want

```
//a[.//div[@class='theme-cell-card Ace']]
```

That will get you the `A` tags that contain a `DIV` that has the desired classes. You can get the `href` from that element along with the contained text.

Since your question is tagged python, you can use something simple like

```
aces = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[.//div[@class='theme-cell-card Ace']]")
for ace in aces
    print(ace.get_attribute("href"))
    print(ace.text)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc Well, thanks for looking into it. I know the xpath/css for 'theme-cell-card Ace' class. But how do I get link and text based on this condition?

Comment: Your XPath locator is not the same as mine. Yours will find a `DIV` where mine finds the `A` tag that you want. From there you can get the `href` of the `A` tag to get the link or you can get contained text... which are both what you want. I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: I've added a simple python example to show how to get the `href` and text from the `A` tags in a loop. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: JeffC , beautiful Thank you. Really appreciate the for the xpath and the sample code. They helped me. The main problem was xpath. I will add the solution in Robotframework

Comment: JeffC, I gave a upvote to your answer, but as my reputation score is under 15, its not showing up. Thanks any away.

Answer (score 0):

```
        @{elements}    Get Webelements    //a[.//div[@class='theme-cell-card Ace']]
        :FOR   ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        \        ${text}    Get Text    ${element}
        \        ${link}    SeleniumLibrary.Get Element Attribute    ${element}    attribute=href
        \        Log to console     ${text}
        \        Log to console     ${link}
```